# Uploading CSV file and convert it into table but when use event, the event is deprecated

Tags: events, angular15

I'm using Angular 15 and the event is deprecated as this:

```js
export class CsvUploadComponent {
  fileSelected: boolean = false;
  showTables: boolean = false;
  tableHeaders: string[] = [];
  tablesData: string[][][] = [];

  onFileSelected(event: any) {
    const file: File = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files![0];
    this.fileSelected = !!file;
  }

  processCSV() {
    if (!this.fileSelected) {
      return;
    }

    const file: File = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files![0];
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      const contents: string = e.target.result;
      this.parseCSV(contents);
      this.showTables = true;
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }

  parseCSV(contents: string) {
    const rows: string[] = contents.split('\n');
    this.tableHeaders = rows[0].split(',');

    this.tablesData = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
      const columns: string[] = rows[i].split(',');
      this.tablesData.push([columns]);
    }
  }
```

In this function Angular says that event is deprecated:

```js
processCSV() {
    if (!this.fileSelected) {
      return;
    }

    const file: File = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files![0];
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      const contents: string = e.target.result;
      this.parseCSV(contents);
      this.showTables = true;
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
```

How can I solve this problem?

i tried another function but it didn't work either, what can I use instead?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What "event" are you talking about? What is the exact error message that you get? When do get the error message: in the editor, when building the application or when running the application? On which line of the code do you get the error message?